# Hadoop: NullPointerException with Custom InputFormat

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I've developed a custom `InputFormat` for Hadoop (including a custom `InputSplit` and a custom `RecordReader`) and I'm experiencing a rare `NullPointerException`.

These classes are going to be used for querying a third-party system which exposes a REST API for records retrieving. Thus, I got inspiration in [`DBInputFormat`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/db/DBInputFormat.java), which is a non-HDFS `InputFormat` as well.

The error I get is the following:

```
Error: java.lang.NullPointerException at
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.initialize(MapTask.java:524)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:762)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:339)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)
```

I've searched the code for [`MapTask`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/branch-2.1.0-beta/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/MapTask.java#L519) (2.1.0 version of Hadoop) and I've seen the problematic part is the initialization of the `RecordReader`:

```
472 NewTrackingRecordReader(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplit split,
473       org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat<K, V> inputFormat,
474       TaskReporter reporter,
475       org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext taskContext)
476       throws InterruptedException, IOException {
...
491    this.real = inputFormat.createRecordReader(split, taskContext);
...
494 }
...
519 @Override
520 public void initialize(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplit split,
521       org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext context
522       ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
523    long bytesInPrev = getInputBytes(fsStats);
524    real.initialize(split, context);
525    long bytesInCurr = getInputBytes(fsStats);
526    fileInputByteCounter.increment(bytesInCurr - bytesInPrev);
527 }
```

Of course, the relevant parts of my code:

```
# MyInputFormat.java

public static void setEnvironmnet(Job job, String host, String port, boolean ssl, String APIKey) {
    backend = new Backend(host, port, ssl, APIKey);
}

public static void addResId(Job job, String resId) {
    Configuration conf = job.getConfiguration();
    String inputs = conf.get(INPUT_RES_IDS, "");

    if (inputs.isEmpty()) {
        inputs += restId;
    } else {
        inputs += "," + resId;
    }

    conf.set(INPUT_RES_IDS, inputs);
}

@Override
public List<InputSplit> getSplits(JobContext job) {
    // resulting splits container
    List<InputSplit> splits = new ArrayList<InputSplit>();

    // get the Job configuration
    Configuration conf = job.getConfiguration();

    // get the inputs, i.e. the list of resource IDs
    String input = conf.get(INPUT_RES_IDS, "");
    String[] resIDs = StringUtils.split(input);

    // iterate on the resIDs
    for (String resID: resIDs) {
       splits.addAll(getSplitsResId(resID, job.getConfiguration()));
    }

    // return the splits
    return splits;
}

@Override
public RecordReader<LongWritable, Text> createRecordReader(InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context) {
    if (backend == null) {
        logger.info("Unable to create a MyRecordReader, it seems the environment was not properly set");
        return null;
    }

    // create a record reader
    return new MyRecordReader(backend, split, context);
}

# MyRecordReader.java

@Override
public void initialize(InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    // get start, end and current positions
    MyInputSplit inputSplit = (MyInputSplit) this.split;
    start = inputSplit.getFirstRecordIndex();
    end = start + inputSplit.getLength();
    current = 0;

    // query the third-party system for the related resource, seeking to the start of the split
    records = backend.getRecords(inputSplit.getResId(), start, end);
}

# MapReduceTest.java

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new MapReduceTest(), args);
    System.exit(res);
}

@Override
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = this.getConf();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "MapReduce test");
    job.setJarByClass(MapReduceTest.class);
    job.setMapperClass(MyMap.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(MyReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(MyReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    job.setInputFormatClass(MyInputFormat.class);
    MyInputFormat.addInput(job, "ca73a799-9c71-4618-806e-7bd0ca1911f4");
    InputFormat.setEnvironmnet(job, "my.host.com", "443", true, "my_api_key");
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Any ideas about what is wrong?

BTW, which is the "good" `InputSplit` the `RecordReader` must use, the one given to the constructor or the one given in the `initialize` method? Anyway I've tried both options and the resulting error is the same :)

Comment: where is `setEnvironment `being called, if at all?

Comment: It is called by the MapReduce application. I've edited the question to include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I read your strack trace `real` is null on line 524.

But don't take my word for it.  Slip an `assert` or `system.out.println` in there and check the value of `real` yourself.

`NullPointerException` almost always means you dotted off something you didn't expect to be null.  Some libraries and collections will throw it at you as their way of saying "this can't be null".

```
Error: java.lang.NullPointerException at
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.initialize(MapTask.java:524)
```

To me this reads as: in the `org.apache.hadoop.mapred` package the `MapTask` class has an inner class `NewTrackingRecordReader` with an `initialize` method that threw a `NullPointerException` at line 524.

```
524 real.initialize( blah, blah) // I actually stopped reading after the dot
```

`this.real` was set on line 491.

```
491 this.real = inputFormat.createRecordReader(split, taskContext);
```

Assuming you haven't left out any more closely scoped `real`s that are masking the `this.real` then we need to look at `inputFormat.createRecordReader(split, taskContext);` If this can return `null` then it might be the culprit.

Turns out it will return `null` when `backend` is null.

```
@Override
public RecordReader<LongWritable, Text> createRecordReader(
    InputSplit split, 
    TaskAttemptContext context) {

    if (backend == null) {
        logger.info("Unable to create a MyRecordReader, " + 
                    "it seems the environment was not properly set");
        return null;
    }

    // create a record reader
    return new MyRecordReader(backend, split, context);
}
```

It looks like `setEnvironmnet` is supposed to set `backend`

```
# MyInputFormat.java

public static void setEnvironmnet(
    Job job, 
    String host, 
    String port, 
    boolean ssl, 
    String APIKey) {

    backend = new Backend(host, port, ssl, APIKey);
}
```

`backend` must be declared somewhere outside `setEnvironment` (or you'd be getting a compiler error).

If `backend` hasn't been set to something non-null upon construction and `setEnvironmnet` was not called before `createRecordReader` then you should expect to get exactly the `NullPointerException` you got.

UPDATE:

As you've noted, since `setEnvironmnet()` is static `backend` must be static as well.  This means that you must be sure other instances aren't setting it to null.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. The problem is the `backend` variable is declared as `static`, i.e. it *belongs* to the java class and thus any other object changing that variable (e.g. to `null`) affects all the other objects of the same class.

Now, `setEnvironment` adds the host, port, ssl usage and the API key as configuration (the same than `setResId` already did with the resource ID); when `createRecordReader` is invoked this configuration is got and the `backend` object is created.

Thanks to CandiedOrange who put me in the right path!

Comment: Good catch with the static.  Not having to deal with variables going from invalid to valid states is one reason I'm starting to think functional programing is cool.